# Getting more specific error messages with PHP LDAP - OID

Tags: php, oracle, ldap, openldap, oid

I'm using PHP to connect to an Oracle OID LDAP - and I'm testing with different account types; in this case I know an account is expired (OID error 9000 - http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/oid.1111/e10029/trblsht.htm#CHDJHCHC) but PHP is just returning me an error 49 (ldap_errno) which is just the generic invalid credentials error.

Is there another function or method to get more verbose messages from the server?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, OID error codes such as this aren't transmitted across the wire (though wireshark will be able to tell you). However, there is often a concept of an extended error.

You should be able to obtain the extended code (and string) using the ldap_get_option function in PHP, using the LDAP_OPT_ERROR_NUMBER and LDAP_OPT_ERROR_STRING options.

The above should be sufficient to give you the 'extended' diagnostic; but remember that this may be directory-implementation-specific.

I see that on http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-get-option.php there is a similar (though for AD) example, that makes use the (apparently undocumented) LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE.